# Java PriorityQueue not working?

Tags: java, queue

I have an Event class which uses the PriorityQueue and a Time class that I defined myself to use with the Event class.

```
static class Event implements Comparable<Event>{
    Customer customer;
    Time eventTime;
    char eventType;

    public int compareTo(Event e){
        int n = e.eventTime.compareTo(eventTime);
        int compare = 0;

        if(n < 0){
            compare = -1;
        }
        else if(n == 0){
            compare = 0;
        }
        else if(n > 0){
            compare = 1;
        }
        return compare; 
    }
}


class Time{
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private boolean isMorning;

    public Time(){
        hour = 0;
        minute = 0;
        isMorning = true;
    }

    public Time(int h, int m, boolean morning){
        hour = h;
        minute = m;
        isMorning = morning;
    }

    public void setTime(int h, int m, boolean morning){
        hour = h;
        minute = m;
        isMorning = morning;
    }

    public int getHour(){
        return hour;
    }

    public int getMinute(){
        return minute;
    }

    public boolean isAM(){
        return isMorning;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String AM = "";
        String min = "";
        if(minute < 10){
            min = ("0" + minute);
        }
        else{
            min = ("" + minute);
        }
        if(isMorning){
            AM = "AM";
        }
        else{
            AM = "PM";
        }
        return ("" + hour + ":" + min + " " + AM);
    }


    public Time plus(int n){
        Time newTime = new Time();
        boolean newMorning = false;
        int minutes = minute + n;
        int newHour = minutes/60;
        int newMinutes = minutes%60;
        hour = hour + newHour;
        if(hour > 12){
            hour = hour - 12;
            if(isMorning){
                newMorning = false;
            }
            else{
                newMorning = true;
            }
        }
        newTime.setTime(hour, newMinutes, newMorning);
        return newTime;

    }

    public int timeDifference(Time t){

        int n = totalMinutes();
        int m = t.totalMinutes();

        return m - n;

    }

    public int compareTo(Time t){
        int n = totalMinutes();
        int m = t.totalMinutes();
        int compare = 0;

        if(n < m){
            compare = -1;
        }
        else if(n == m){
            compare = 0;
        }
        else if(n > m){
            compare = 1;
        }
        return compare;
    }

    private int totalMinutes(){
        int tempMinute = 0;
        if(!isMorning){
            if(hour == 12){

            }
            else{
            hour = hour + 12;
            tempMinute = (hour*60) + minute;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(hour == 12){
                tempMinute = minute;
            }
            else{
                tempMinute = (hour*60) + minute;
            }
        }
        return tempMinute;
    }

}
```

This isn't all of my code as I have others just holding the values that will later be inserted into the Event queue. When I check the time outside of the Event queue it matches the time that it should be, say I have a Time object as 11:22 AM, but when I insert it into the Event queue my time changes to 23:22 AM. For some reason it is adding 12 hours within the Event queue and I don't understand why.

---

Figured it out the totalMinutes() method was messing with the hours because it was being called when using compareTo() or timeDifference() implicitly. Thank you for the help!

---

Comment: Looks to me like you have your compareTo backwards. Haven't read all your code, though.

Comment: The `Time.plus` method seems to mess with the instance's own `hour` instead of the new Time's `hour`.

Comment: `Time.totalMinutes` also seems to be messing with the `hour` instance field when it really shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

First, `totalMinutes()` messes with the `hour` field when it shouldn't. It should use a local variable.

Second, your entire `Event.compareTo(Event e)` method can be reduced to

```
return e.eventTime.compareTo(eventTime);
```

which is back to front, unless you want the most recent times first. Try

```
return eventTime.compareTo(e.eventTime);
```